# jQuery Datatables with Ajax function throws error on ajax.reload()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a datatable which im trying to populate using an ajax function. 
I'd like to also be able to reload the table from a button click.

Im trying to use the flavor of jQuery datatables that allows me to use a custom function to execute the actual ajax. It correctly loads the data on init but throws an error when i try to reload it.

**Error:**

[image]

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="SearchBtn">Submit</button>

<table id="ResultsTable" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"></table>
```

**JS:**

```
const service = {
  getResults: function() {
    return $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}

$(function() {
  const dataTableConfig = {
    ajax: async function(data, callback, settings) {
      let response = await service.getResults();
      const formattedResponse = {
        data: response.map(i => Object.values(i))
      };
      callback(formattedResponse);
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "Name"
      },
      {
        title: "Position"
      },
      {
        title: "Office"
      },
      {
        title: "Extn."
      },
      {
        title: "Start date"
      },
      {
        title: "Salary"
      }
    ]
  };
  const UI = {
    SearchBtn: $("#SearchBtn"),
    ResultsTable: $('#ResultsTable').DataTable(dataTableConfig)
  };
  UI.SearchBtn.click(function() {
    UI.ResultsTable.ajax.reload();
  });
});
```

**MVCE Example with error (click submit button to see it):**

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/bkzahydg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) by default returns a deferred object you can elaborate with [.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) instead of await. Hence, you don't need to mess await/async with an already asynchronous behavior.

I would suggest to change your ajax part to:

```
ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
    service.getResults().then(function (response) {
        const formattedResponse = {
            data: response.map(i => Object.values(i))
        };
        callback(formattedResponse);
    })
},
```

```js
const service = {
  getResults: function () {
      return $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}

const dataTableConfig = {
    ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
        service.getResults().then(function (response) {
            const formattedResponse = {
                data: response.map(i => Object.values(i))
            };
            callback(formattedResponse);
        })
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "Name"
    }, {
        title: "Position"
    }, {
        title: "Office"
    }, {
        title: "Extn."
    }, {
        title: "Start date"
    }, {
        title: "Salary"
    }
    ]
};
const UI = {
    SearchBtn: $("#SearchBtn"),
    ResultsTable: $('#ResultsTable').DataTable(dataTableConfig)
};
UI.SearchBtn.click(function () {
    UI.ResultsTable.ajax.reload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="SearchBtn">Submit</button>
<table id="ResultsTable" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works. But i dont understand why mine doesnt. As far as i know, `service.getResults().then(func)` is exactly the same as `let respo = await service.getResults() ; func(resp);`

guess ill have to research some more.